# Liquibase SQL Server and Oracle version support

Tags: database, version, liquibase

Where can I find information on which database versions Liquibase supports? For Flyway they have a [handy summary of supported versions](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/sqlserver) and was wondering if the same existed for Liquibase?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only t"hing supported databases" documentation Liquibase has is [this one](https://www.liquibase.org/databases.html).

[image]

I personally can't recall any issues regarding database versions.